# Error in Nuget while installing package

Tags: nuget

I got an error while installing package from Nuget. The error is:

> The parameter is incorrect.
>
> An when using Nuget in WebMatrix, it's still error.
>  The following
>   is stack strace in WebMatrix
>  An error occurred. The parameter is
>   incorrect. System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The
>   parameter is incorrect. at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Unprotect(Byte[]
>   encryptedData, Byte[] optionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope scope) at
>   NuGet.EncryptionUtility.DecryptString(String encryptedString) at
>   NuGet.SettingsExtensions.GetDecryptedValue(ISettings settings, String
>   section, String key) at
>   NuGet.SettingsExtensions.GetConfigValue(ISettings settings, String
>   key, Boolean decrypt) at NuGet.ProxyCache.GetUserConfiguredProxy() at
>   NuGet.ProxyCache.GetProxy(Uri uri) at
>   NuGet.RequestHelper.GetResponse(Func`1 createRequest, Action`1
>   prepareRequest, IProxyCache proxyCache, ICredentialCache
>   credentialCache, ICredentialProvider credentialProvider) at
>   NuGet.HttpClient.GetResponse() at
>   NuGet.RedirectedHttpClient.GetResponseUri(HttpClient client) at
>   NuGet.RedirectedHttpClient.EnsureClient() at
>   System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() at
>   System.Lazy`1.get_Value() at NuGet.MemoryCache.GetOrAdd[T](Object
>   cacheKey, Func`1 factory, TimeSpan expiration, Boolean
>   absoluteExpiration) at NuGet.RedirectedHttpClient.get_CachedClient()
>   at NuGet.RedirectedHttpClient.get_Uri() at
>   NuGet.DataServicePackageRepository.get_Context() at
>   NuGet.DataServicePackageRepository.Search(String searchTerm,
>   IEnumerable`1 targetFrameworks, Boolean allowPrereleaseVersions) at
>   NuGet.PackageRepositoryExtensions.Search(IPackageRepository
>   repository, String searchTerm, IEnumerable`1 targetFrameworks, Boolean
>   allowPrereleaseVersions) at
>   Microsoft.WebMatrix.PackageManagement.WebProjectManager.GetRemotePackages(String
>   searchTerms, Boolean filterPreferred) at
>   Microsoft.WebMatrix.NuGet.NuGetPackageManager.GetRemotePackages() at
>   Microsoft.WebMatrix.NuGet.Data.VirtualizingListViewFilter.OnQueryChanged()
>   at
>   Microsoft.WebMatrix.NuGet.Data.VirtualizingListViewFilter.set_PackageManager(INuGetPackageManager
>   value) at Microsoft.WebMatrix.NuGet.FilterManager.UpdateAllFilter() at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke() at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

Comment: Please add, waht you did to get this error. You mentioned "During installation"... How did you install it on which system?

Comment: For example, when I type "Install-package jquery" in console, it gives me this error

Comment: and you are getting it with every package that you try to install?

Comment: yes, every package. I think the error comes from Install-Package function

Answer (score 0):

There is no package manager console for webmatrix. Do you have visual studio installed on the same machine?

what if you open the same website in visual studio and type install-package *** there?

Also, any special installation or setup that you do?